How to stop drf spectacular autogenerating schema
Ι am using drf spectacular to produce my schema. In some cases it produces some endpoints that are not used or wanted to be used.I want  rule them out. everything i tried seems pointless since the view we have can indeed be used for the purposes that the schema shows but we dont want that to show.
I try to automate my endpoint and views documentation I expected it to be fine but it isnt

suggesting additional tags for your question to be found: schema, openapi, django-rest-framework. Look for relevant tags that are being followed.

Probably describe your latest attempts, with link to documentation

[mre] possible?
